# Small TestNG app won't run correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I created a Java Project in Eclipse and ran some TestNG files successfully. Now I've created a new Java Project and find out my TestNG files won't run as expected.

So, to troubleshoot, I created a very simple test2.class file shown below for my first (previous) Java Project and the same file for my new java Project (top line changed to reflect package name). When I execute this file as a TestNG app, it runs fine in my first project (prints out 'Test' in the console window). However, when I run it in the same way in my new project, nothing prints out and I don't see any errors.

I checked my Java Build Paths and they are the same for both. So, obviously I am missing something in my new java project???

```java
package com.selftechy.seltests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Test2 { 
    @Test
    public void Test() { 
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: you still do see the option of "Run as TestNG Test" in your new project?

Comment: also, if you were interested, you should check out http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium if you are interesting in learning selenium. it's a polished "getting started" framework using Selenium with java, maven and jUnit.

Comment: >you still do see the option of "Run as TestNG Test" in your new project?
Yes

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the sky...

If this is your actual code listed, it has a compilation error because of the missing '}' in the method. So the TestNG execution does not even start.

Comment: There's one another right brace after the formatted code snippet. It's simply unformatted.

Comment: Yes, this is my actual code. I ran Validate and it didn't report any errors. I don't see where you are referring to missing right brace as I see balanced curly braces?

Comment: This code runs fine:
package com.msgVault;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test2 { 
  @Test
  public void Test() { 
       System.out.println("Test");
    }

}

Comment: This code runs but doesn't print "Test":
package com.selftechy.seltests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {
 @Test
 public void loginTest() {
       System.out.println("Test");
 }

}

Comment: @RalphF I've just edited the code in your question, so the braces are now balanced. See your initial code: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20619865/1

Comment: We must have a browser difference...your edited code is the same as my original posting...however, I still did copy your edited code and ran it with the same results on my end: no console output of Test.

Comment: The only difference is the first line: package com.selftechy.seltests; in one file and package com.msgVault; in the other file. So, there must be something I have missed declaring in package com.selftechy.seltests; that is preventing TestNG from working.

Comment: Solution: I don't really understand why, but when I removed the package org.testing.annotations, TestNG finally ran and output Test in the console.